# How can I protect my notebook file with a password to open and save changes?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I want to protect my .nb file with a password, because now I'm using a free access computer in my university. Everybody student in my university can use that computer and I do not want my .nb file can be modified. I would like to create a .nb file that request some password to open it and request the same password to save changes. Please advise me.

Comment: Related thread on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/371808).

Comment: and obviously, request the password to save changes too.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica stack exchange! Spend a minute or two and take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already done so. Also, for best results, you should show what you've tried and provide a minimal example that shows your problem.

Comment: Also, these comments are not a permanent fixture (they may be deleted, appear out of order, etc.), so it's usually better to edit your question to include details instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: If you have a version of Mathematica with cloud support (version 9 and 10) you could save your file in the cloud. Access is based on a login/password combo of your (free) Wolfram user account.

Comment: Marco, you seem to have accidentally created two accounts. Visit this page for instructions on how to merge the two accounts back into one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @MarcoB, you were pointing him to SO. How could you?! :P (Fixed your comment. ;) )

Comment: I would use [7zip with encryption](http://www.medicalnerds.com/how-to-encrypt-zip-files-securely-using-7zip/).